# Include license file in readme

Tags: github, pypi, transcrypt

I have a file README.rst that I use both for PyPi and GitHub.

Since I want to include a license file also on GitHub, it contains the line:

```
.. include:: transcrypt/license_reference.txt
```

However this works neither on PyPi (whole file not parsed correctly) nor on GitHub (include directive ignored)

Can anyone shed a light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Github's team thinks (and they are probably right) that allowing the include directive could be a major security flaw : https://github.com/github/markup/issues/172

I suppose they've deactivated the [file-insertion-enabled](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#file-insertion-enabled) parameter of their rst render engine :)

Comment: Probably true. Only I have a hard time to imagine why including a local file with some weird content is more dangerous than including that content directly in the main readme. Could anyone explain?